# Stop Visual Web Developer from putting "span lang="en-us" tags

Tags: visual-studio, html

I'm working my way through figuring out how VWD applies styles depending on how you attempt to modify the formatting for text, and noticed it keeps putting in an

```
span lang="en-us"
```

tag in front of things. A check of google didn't produce anything that was relevent for VWD, so I thought I'd ask if anyone knows how to prevent this tag from being added?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Google results do seem to indicate similar problems in this 'family' of products (Frontpage, ExpressionWeb)

Did you try the solutions for these products? Like specify the language in the html tag?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

Source: 
http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/web/thread/85329a36-ab68-4bb9-a5a3-a2968e4d4044